# Working with local ViewModel in MVVM WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am having trouble accessing my ViewModel when working with my view.

I have a project named **BankManagerApplication**. Within that I have the various files associated with a new WPF application. I have created three seperate folders **Model**, **ViewModel** and **View**.

At the moment there is a UserModel class in the Model folder with the following fields;

```
namespace BankManagerApplication.Model
{
    public class UserModel
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public double AccountBallance { get; set; }
    }
}
```

a blank view in the View folder with just a grid inside;

```
<Window x:Class="BankManagerApplication.View.MainWindowView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindowView" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and also a blank ViewModel in the ViewModel folder;

```
namespace BankManagerApplication.ViewModel
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel
    {
    }
}
```

when i try to reference the ViewModel in my XAML like so;

```
<Window x:Class="BankManagerApplication.View.MainWindowView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindowView" Height="300" Width="300"
        xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:BankManagerApplication.ViewModel">
    <Grid>
        <viewmodel:MainWindowViewModel></viewmodel:MainWindowViewModel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

i get the error

> The name 'MainWindowViewModel does not exist in the namespace
>   "clr-namespace:BankManagerApplication.ViewModel'

I have only just started learning WPF and this error is throwing me off before I have really begun

Comment: Have you built the project containing the ViewModel yet?

Comment: Usually the ViewModel would be assigned to the DataSource of a regular view control (such as a Window, Grid or other control). It is rather unusual to "new-up" a viewmodel within the XAML of a view.

Comment: Besides, you can't add that class to a grid. Its not allowed as a child of Grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add it to a Grid control because it is not a UIElement. Your viewmodel will be the DataContext of your view:

```
<Window x:Class="BankManagerApplication.View.MainWindowView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindowView" Height="300" Width="300"
    xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:BankManagerApplication.ViewModel">
    <Window.DataContext>
       <viewmodel:MainWindowViewModel></viewmodel:MainWindowViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
```